# formatting file version and legalcopyright in rc file

Tags: windows, rc

I have defined a rc file for my dll with following details

```
    VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company Inc."
    VALUE "FileDescription", "Dll for XYZ"
    VALUE "FileVersion", "1.00"
    VALUE "InternalName", "MyDll"
    VALUE "ProductName", "MyProduct"
    VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.00"
    VALUE "Build ID", "10500 "
    VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2004-2011 My Company Inc. All rights reserved."
```

Right click on the file and selecting properties shows the following

```
   File version: 0.1.00
   Description:  Dll for XYZ
   Copyright:    Copyright © 2004-2011 My Company Inc. Al
```

First issue is the file version. Not sure why it is prepending 0. before the file version
Can we format that string in rc file?

Second, the copyright text is truncated after 40 characters.User has to drag the cursor on the string to read entire string.
Can we set the text to wrap so entire string is visible? I understand that the copyright string can be reduced to under 40 characters but wanted to know if we can wrap that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dotted quad for version number and product number

```
VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
```

In my product group, we use the first number in the set as the major version, the second as the minor version, the third is the build (patch) number, and the fourth is a 4 digit representation of the date.  E.g. "8.1.1234.0614"

Our copyright string gets truncated too.  But I don't feel so bad... all the EXEs and DLLs that ship by MS in c:\windows have truncated copyright strings. :)

Comment: Thanks @selbie. I would use that advice for file versioning. Also not worried about copyright notice. On Win7, there is no way to see the entire string.